# django not getting the online parameter when submitting a form

Tags: django

I submit a form with two inputs to search a table. My code doesn't get the value of 'namequery' instead of displaying all data in table. What did I do wrong here? Thanks for any help!
The url is 
http://..../chinook/search/?namequery=rand&affquery=

search.html

```
  <h3 class="labs-background-title">Search results for <em id="search-name">{{ namequery }}</em>:</h3>
  {% if object_list %}
    {% for obj in object_list %}
      {{ obj.lname }} <br />
      {{ obj.clustering }} <br />
  {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <h3>No matches found.</h3>
  {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
class SearchView(generic.ListView):
model = Pitable 
template_name = 'chinook/search.html'


def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        namequery = self.kwargs['namequery']
    except:
        namequery = ''
    if (namequery != ''):
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(lname = namequery)
    else:
        object_list = self.model.objects.all()
    return object_list
```

The return page display all data, shows the {{namequery}} is empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things wrong here.

Firstly, 'namequery' is not a URL kwarg, it is a GET query parameter. You need to get it from `self.request['namequery']`.

Secondly, **never ever** use a blank except. The only exception that could possibly happen there is KeyError, so catch that. But a better way of writing all four lines would be:

```
namequery = self.request.GET.get('namequery')
```

Thirdly, to display the value of namequery in the template you need to add it to the context data.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['namequery'] = self.request.GET.get('namequery')
    return context
```